# How to connect domain name with WordPress container in Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker, dns, docker-container, domain-name

I have installed a WordPress container in the Docker app on my server. It's working when I am using my IP address and the port number `myip:8000`. But the question is that how to connect with a domain.
I have added "A" records on my DNS management but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find on which interface is the container listening. It may be it listens on local interface only: `10.10.10.10:8000` and not on external IP `w.x.y.z:8000`